# The error: unrecognized arguments: for a json file to passed into the arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I have a train.py script which uses the argparse to parse arguments but it showing this error.

```
parser.add_argument('--config', dest='config', required=True, type= str ,                         # config.json file path
                    help='hyperparameter of Model in json format')

parser.add_argument('-l', '--log', default="log.txt", type=str,                         # log file
                    help='log file')
```

The error that comes up is this :

```
train.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --config /home/user/MODEL/tools/config.json --log /home/user/MODEL/logs/log.txt
```

I am not getting what is going wrong here.The argument to be passed is a config.json file which has specifications for my model to be trained.

```
args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args(['--config', '-l', '--log'])
```

I added above line now I am getting an error like this: usage: `train.py [-h] [-j N] [--epochs N] [-b N] [--lr LR] [--momentum M] [--weight-decay W] [--clip CLIP] --config CONFIG [--arch {Custom}] [-l LOG] train.py: error: argument --config: expected one argument:`

This is the command passed onto the terminal :

```
python train.py --config=/home/user/MODEL/tools/config.json --log /home/user/MODEL/logs/log.txt 2>&1 | tee /home/user/MODEL/logs/train.log
```

Comment: When putting the above into a test file it does not show the error. Maybe you should try to cut down your main python program.

Comment: What's the `usage` message?  Does it correspond to the arguments you defined, or are there a lot of arguments that you didn't specify.  I suspect there's another parser in your code that does not expect a `--config` flag.

Comment: @hpaulj actually there are other arguments too but have been provided with default values. And there isn't any duplicate --config argument only one has been provided.

Comment: Test the help, '-h'.  Another thing to look at `sys.argv`, to make sure the shell isn't giving any surprises.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line below the above two lines:

```py
parser.add_argument('--config', dest='config', required=True, type= str ,                         # config.json file path
                    help='hyperparameter of Model in json format')

parser.add_argument('-l', '--log', default="log.txt", type=str,                         # log file
                    help='log file')
args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args(['--config', '-l', '--log'])
```

Comment: I added those line now I am getting an error like this:                                                            usage: train.py [-h] [-j N] [--epochs N] [-b N] [--lr LR]
                         [--momentum M] [--weight-decay W] [--clip CLIP]
                         --config CONFIG [--arch {Custom}] [-l LOG]
train.py:   error: argument --config: expected one argument:

Comment: This is what I am passing in the command line:                                             
python train.py --config=/home/user/MODEL/tools/config.json --log /home/user/MODEL/logs/log.txt 2>&1 | tee /home/user/MODEL/logs/train.log

Comment: @SayoojBalakrishnan add these 2 comments with proper formatting to your question, please. Question should have all info to reproduce problem, that makes the question answerable.

Comment: (General note: there is no need to add "hope this helps", and other similar material to answers. Everyone posts an answer in the hope that it helps, and we surely don't need 27M copies of it. Technical writing is preferred here).